# solr search in Django application

Tags: django, django-haystack, solr-schema, solr-search

1. There are questions in database. Solr search is giving results, but I want the ranking of the questions based on the text I'm searching. But search giving results based on id's of the questions.
2. In solr.xml file I have the schema based on that indexing is happening.
3. What should i do the xml file to get the search results based on ranking.